# Calculate a template binding "out of the DOM" with VueJs

Tags: templates, vue.js, vuejs2

I probably missed a big piece of the framework but there's my question.
I would like to know if there is a way to use the template binding provided by VueJs2 outside of the DOM. For example:

- I have a Vue template as a string
- I have it's Json data equivalent

I would like to calculate this binding within a method or a computed value of my Vue object and to put it into my DOM. 
Something like:

`let domOrDomString = Vue.bind(stringTemplate, data);`

I whant to do this because the template can take many values and I can't put all the possibilities within the initial template of my Vue instance.

Thank you for your help!

**Edit**

If it is not possible because it's not supposed to be done without VueX or Vue cli, let me know that and I will probably upgrade my stack.

Comment: Something like this? https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/jpaRVo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially,

```
function generateHtml(template, data){
  const rendered = new Vue({template, data}).$mount()
  return rendered.$el
}
```

Should do what I expect you want.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanx for the pen that clearly show that.